# Geometry problem with circles and arcs

Tags: geometry, circles

In the diagram, $\angle U = 30^\circ$, arc $XY$ is $170^\circ$, and arc $VW$ is $110^\circ$. Find arc $WY$, in degrees.

[image]

I got $55^\circ$ but apparently it's wrong.

Comment: You should give your solution; someone may be able to easily identify your error; this  will also help people understand what tools and techniques you are familiar with. Also, you might as well also give the correct answer, so that others can check their own work.

Comment: If arc $WY$ is $55$ degrees then $\angle WVY = 27.5^\circ$ and $\angle U$ is even smaller. But you are given $\angle U = 30^\circ.$ So it should be obvious that $55^\circ$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the figure such that $XY$ is horizontal. Then draw provisional $V'W'$ forming an angle of $110^\circ$ at the center $O$ of the circle, so that $V'W'$ is horizontal as well. Now  rotate $V'W'$ clockwise into the definitive position $VW$ so that at $U$ you obtain the angle $30^\circ$. Looking at all angles and half-angles in your figure then shows you that the angle you desire is $70^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Use this fact about two secants that meet at a point outside the circle:
$\newcommand{arc}{\mathop{\mathrm{arc}}}$
$$ \frac12(\arc WY - \arc XV) = \angle U = 30^\circ. $$

Also use the fact that the circle is divided into four arcs:

$$ \arc WY + \arc XV = 360^\circ - \arc XY - \arc VW
 = 360^\circ - 170 ^\circ - 110^\circ = 80^\circ. $$

Now you have two equations in just two unknowns, $\arc WY$ and $\arc XV.$
Solve for $\arc WY.$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Construct $YV$ as the diameter of the circle. Then

\begin{align}
\angle XOY&=170^\circ
,\\
\angle XWY&=85^\circ
,\\
\angle XYO=\angle OYX=\angle VWX
&=5^\circ
,\\
\angle VOX&=10^\circ
,\\
\angle YOV&=70^\circ
,\\
\angle VYU&=60^\circ
,\\
\angle UWY&=90^\circ
,\\
\angle YUW&=30^\circ
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

Alternatively,

[image]

\begin{align}
\triangle UWY:\quad
\angle YUW&+\angle UWY+\angle WYU
=180^\circ
,\\
\angle UWY&=
\angle UWO+\angle OWY
=125^\circ-\tfrac12\phi
,\\
\angle WYU&=
\angle WUO+\angle OYU
=95^\circ-\tfrac12\phi
,\\
30^\circ+
125^\circ&-\tfrac12\phi
+95^\circ-\tfrac12\phi
=180^\circ
,\\
\phi&=70^\circ
.
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you choose to make $YV$ a diameter as your first step? Lucky guess? Work you did elsewhere before writing up this proof?

Comment: @David K: Yes, it was a natural choice in order to simplify the construction, 
and check its validity.